# MySQL - Select Distinct Count with Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count, distinct, analytics

I'm having trouble with a MySQL query to generate a report of the number of products using a specific software version.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Count(ps.software_id) AS count, 
       s.software_id 
FROM   software s, 
       product_software ps, 
       products p 
WHERE  s.software_id = ps.software_id 
       AND p.product_id = ps.product_id 
       AND p.product_name = 'ProdA' 
GROUP  BY ps.software_id
```

The trouble is, the product_software table looks like this:

```
product_software_id        product_id          software_id
1                          1                   1
2                          2                   1
3                          3                   1
4                          1                   2
5                          2                   2
6                          1                   3
7                          4                   3
8                          5                   3
```

The current output of the query is:

```
count       software_id
3           1
2           2
3           3
```

The correct (expected) output should be:

```
count       software_id
0           1
1           2
3           3
```

I only want to include the most recent (highest product_software_id) entry in the query. (i.e. software_id and product_id should both be unique).

Comment: Can you add more sample data to your product_software table, to illustrate other scenarios, such as one where the desired count should be 2?

Comment: Can you explain why your expected result lists count=3 for software_id=3, but for others count=1. What are the rules?

Comment: @cha count = 3 for software_id = 3 because there are 3 products with software_id = 3. (product ids: 1, 4, 5).
software_id 2 has only 1 product (product_id 2)
software_id 1 has no products (it had v1, but was then upgraded to v2, and finally v3 - so should only report v3)

Comment: Hi Paul, Please give clearly what do you need and what is the criteria. we don't ubderstand why it is 0 for 1 and 1 for 2 and 3 for 3 in final output. On what basis you need this?

Comment: @Paul: very funny. How do you expect us to know based on the data you have provided who have updated to the latest version v3 and who stays on v2 or v1. Re-read your question. Can you see v2 or v3 somewhere?

Comment: Shouldn't product 3 be counted as still being on v1?

Answer (score 2):

For get highest product_software_id for specific product, you must first join 2  product_software table to filter the last one (your can create a view called v_product_software)

```
Select p1.* from product_software p1 left join product_software laster on p1.product_id = laster.product_id and p1.product_software_id < laster.product_software_id
where isnull(laster.product_software_id)
```

--> this query return

```
product_software_id        product_id          software_id
3                          3                   1
5                          2                   2
6                          1                   3
7                          4                   3
8                          5                   3
```

after that, run your sql will return (change product_software to v_product_software)

```
count       software_id
0*          1
1           2
3           3
```

For row 1, software_id = 1 will have product with id=3, but i think the product name is difference from 'ProdA' so the result will be 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I found the answer. Here it is if it will help anyone going forward:

```
select Count(counted) as count, software_id 
from (select  Max(ps.software_id) as counted,
Max(s.software_id) software_id,
from software s
inner join product_software ps
on s.software_id = ps.software_id
inner join products p  
on p.product_id = ps.product_id
where p.product_name='ProdA'
group by p.product_id
) as counts
group by counted
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the highest version for each product, simply group by product.

```
Select product_id, max(software_id)
  From product_software
  group by product_id
```

From that, count products by software id.

```
with v as
( select product_id, max(software_id) curr_ver
    from product_software
    group by product_id
)
select count(*), curr_ver
  from v
  group by curr_ver
  order by curr_ver
```

Comment: This won't fly with `WITH`. MySQL stil lacks support for CTEs.